# TableView frequent reload stops user interaction of button inside cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

Working on one screen where there is `UITableView` and reusable `UITableViewCell` with `UIButton` actions

- `UITableView` is having high (twice in ms) reload frequency because of reloading frequently, the cell is losing user interaction and it makes hard for the user to click the `UIButton` inside the cell

Therefore, Looking for another way around to achieve this scenario.

Comment: You are almost certainly doing something in your "high reload frequency" that you shouldn't be doing. We need to see ***what you're currently doing*** to have any chance of helping you resolve the issue. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to handle frequent table updates: instead of calling `tableView.reloadData()` twice a second, consider using the following pattern:

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    (cell as? CustomCell).configure(context: self.dataArray[tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)]
}
```

This will prevent table view from heavyweight full calculations like contentSize, etc, twice a second. Call reloadData only when your dataArray is updated.

This will work if you don't need significant table updates, but something like timer labels refresh. For this kind of operations, full table reload is definitely redundant, you can only update visible content cell subviews.

Comment: visibleCells with GCD blocks work Smooth, Thanks